# If $4x - 3$ is a factor of $4x^3 - 23x^2 + px + 27$, find the value of $p$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Okay so I got $x^2 - 5x (p-15)/4 + 27$ for my final answer but I'm sure this is not right. How do I solve and get the right answer for $p$?

I did long division up until I got to the part with $px$, when I got to this part I got $(p-15)x$. I then put $4x$ over $1$ and divided into $(p-15)x$ which in the process canceled out the $x$'s and then I got $(p-15)$.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your question.

Comment: Could you please show your steps as to how you got to that result? Otherwise this would just attract downvotes and close votes

Comment: If $(4x-3)$ is a factor of polynomial $f(x)$ then $f(\frac 34) = 0$

Comment: Perform polynomial long division and set the remainder equal to zero.

Comment: The Synthetic Division by  $x-\frac{3}{4}$ works quite well in this situation, better than the long division I think. The remainder is $27+\frac{3}{4}(p-15)$, which should be $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step $1$:** $$4x^3-23x^2+px+27=(4x-3)(?x^2\,+\,?x\,+\,?)$$

**Step $2$:** Since $4x^3=4x\cdot1x^2$ and $27=-3\cdot(-9)$, $$4x^3-23x^2+px+27=(4x-3)(\color{red}1x^2\,+\,?x\,+\,\color{blue}{-9})$$

**Step $3$:** $$4x^3-23x^2+px+27=(4x-3)(x^2+\color{green}ux-9)\\\implies -23x^2=4ux^2-3x^2\implies u=-5$$

**Step $4$:** Expand $(4x-3)(x^2-5x-9)$ to find the coefficient of $x$.

Answer (score 1):

$4x^3-23x^2+px+27=$

$ (4x-3)q(x)$,

where $q(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $2.$

$(4x-3)q(x)=0$ has a root at

$x=3/4.$

Hence

$4(3/4)^3-23(3/4)^2 +p(3/4) +27=0.$

Solve for $p$.

Answer (score 0):

You got down to needing $(p-15)x+27$ to be divisible by $4x-3$.  As both are linear the quotient is a constant so you have $$(p-15)x+27=k(4x-3)\\(p-15)x+27=4kx-3k$$
To make the constant terms match we must have $k=-9$ so 
$$p-15=-36\\p=-21$$

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer long division we have:

$4x^3 -23x^2 +px +27  \space | \space 4x-3$ which is $x^2-5x+\frac{p-15}{4}$ with the remainder: $\frac{3p-45}{4}+27$. We need the remainder to be zero. So  $\frac{3p-45}{4}+27=0$ and $p=-\frac{63}{3}=-21$

Answer (score 0):

Alt. hint:   let the three roots be $\,a = \dfrac{3}{4}, b, c\,$, then by [Vieta's relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas):

- $\;a+b+c = \dfrac{23}{4} \;\;\implies\;\; b+c = 5$
- $\;abc = - \dfrac{27}{4} \;\;\implies\;\; bc = -9$

It follows that $\,\dfrac{p}{4}=ab+ac+bc=a \cdot (b+c)+bc= \dfrac{3}{4} \cdot 5 -9 =\ldots\,$

Answer (score 0):

If $4x^3-23x^2+px+27$ is divisible by $4x-3$, the quotient must be of the form $x^2+ax-9$ in order to get the lead and constant coefficients to agree.  Expanding

$$(4x-3)(x^2+ax-9)=4x^3+(4a-3)x^2-(36+3a)x+27$$

we see that $4a-3=-23$ implies $a=-5$, from which it follows that

$$p=-(36+3a)=-(36-15)=-21$$